# Java JSON: как игнорировать двойные ковычки в строках при парсинге?

Tags: java, json

Мне нужно пропарсить JSON строку, в которой есть строковое значение, в котором присутствует двойная ковычка. Например,

```
   {
   "firstName": "Иван",
   "lastName": "Иванов "Иванов"",
   }
```

Соответственно пишу такой код

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

И получаю ошибку

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 44 of {"firstName": "Иван",
W/System.err: "lastName": "Иванов "Иванов"",
W/System.err: }
```

jsonString получаю с сервера, которым я не владею, то есть на уровне сервера сделать ничего не могу.

Answer (score 6):

Это изначально некорректный JSON. Соответственно проблема не в парсинге, а в данных. Нужно сделать их корректными. Пример:

```
{
   "firstName": "Иван",
   "lastName": "Иванов \"Иванов\"",
}
```

Для проверки сами можете посмотреть свой json вот тут http://json.parser.online.fr/ и убедиться, что он нерабочий, а вариант выше - вполне.

возмонжо можно к строке применять декодирование, добавление обратных слешей. что-то типа JsonStringEncoder у Jackson парсера. Но скорее просто на сервер нужно правильно формировать строку

Answer (score -2):

Напишите утильный метод который будем приводить строку к валидному виду, передайте ему свой стринг и удалите одну кавычку если в строке встречаются 2 кавычки подряд, а дальше просто верните новую строку.

Comment: А если они идут не подряд? Такой парсинг - дело гиблое.

Comment: @LEQADA да, конечно тот еще велосипед, но если нет возможности править что-то на беке как один из вариантов рассмотреть можно. А то что кавычка не подряд может идти не заметил сразу сори:) а вообще вот еще одно костыльное решение: передаем строку, удаляем в ней все кавычка, а потом вставляем кавычки если встречается перенос/новая буква после символа '{'/ символ ':'/символ ',' и т.д. (при условии что в модельке будут только стринги).